# What would it take to get CarPlay in an older Outback model?

Tags: subaru, navigation, outback

I have a 2011 Subaru Outback and quite simply I'm looking for a way to get CarPlay in it. It already has a screen and bluetooth but do i have to buy a new screen to get car play?

Is there a software and/or hardware update available to get CarPlay in older models of Outback?

Comment: Also, can someone with high enough rep create and add the `CarPlay` tag to my question?

Comment: @SolarMike: Not sure how many `CarPlay` questions would be asked but the tag would aptly classify the question when used. In case the tag is being misused or not being used at all, it won't cost anything to burn it later.

Comment: @SolarMike: I'm obviously trying to connect my iPhone. I can currently connect it through BlueTooth, USB and aux too for audio only mode. However, I'm not looking to connect through CarPlay for *more* connectivity. I'm, instead, looking for *right* way to connect the iPhone to car so that I can use my phone (navigation, apps,...) through the car. The interface that Subaru offers, just pales in front of CarPlay. (Have you interacted with CarPlay?)

Comment: @SolarMike: Androids connect through Android Auto. iOSes connect through CarPlay.

Comment: see here for a list of compatible models that work with carplay : https://www.apple.com/ios/carplay/available-models/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed.

In fact not just a Subaru/Outback, if you have purchased a car without CarPlay inbuilt, it can be added to your car afterwards using an after market system which, at the time of writing this answer, is available from the following sellers:

- [Alpine](http://www.alpine-usa.com/index.php/product/view/apple-wireless-carplay-ilx-107)
- [Clarion](http://www.clarion.com/us/en/products-personal/multimedia/NX807/)
- [Kenwood](http://www.kenwood.com/usa/car/ddxsp/apple.html)
- [Pioneer](http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/CarPlay/)
- [Sony](https://www.sony.com/electronics/in-car-receivers-players/xav-ax100)

Further, separate support for using Siri (only) can be added as well.

Comment: Does this require the original ICE as supplied by the manufacturer to be replaced? Warranty issues?

Comment: For those who wonder: ICE probably means in-car entertainment. I have seen the ICE term more often used for internal combustion engine, which definitely doesn't need replacement here.

Comment: @SolarMike: Yes it requires replacement of OEM part. About warranty, I'm guessing it would depend on your brand and dealer. At some places, when the dealer does the replacement, they would leave your warranty intact. Others may allow you to have the replacement anywhere and still let you have your original warranty. Essentially, it depends on your specific case. Best is to confirm with your dealer.

Comment: @SolarMike: That depends on what you mean by "warranty issues". If you're asking if Subaru will recognize the bumper-to-bumper warranty, then yes, they should recognize the warranty for any issues and/or parts that are still stock and not caused by the aftermarket unit. Will Subaru fix issues with your Pioneer headunit? No. Will Subaru fix issues with your wheel bearings? Yes.

Comment: @Ellesedil so will they fix damaged speakers? It's obvious they will continue for wheel bearings....

Comment: That will depend on the damage. If you blow out 3 speakers due to excessive volume, it may be difficult to show that the head unit wasn't responsible for it. If it's an electrical short or something, then you have a strong case for warranty coverage. Warranties are only voided by aftermarket parts if it can be shown that the aftermarket part could be directly responsible for the issue. Just because the parts are related to each other is not sufficient, although plenty of dealerships will try to make that case anyway. When it doubt, (threaten to) escalate it to the manufacturer (Subaru).